# Data Augmentation: keras ImageDataGenerator vs manual loading and augmenting

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am training a model in Tensorflow and I want to implement an effective **on-line data augmentation**, and I want it to work fast enough so that it won't be a bottleneck in training (so that the data would be feeded to GPU faster than the forward-backward cycle of the model on GPU). However, I previously had experience with Keras, and its [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) seems to work pretty neat. So my question is:

> Should I use Keras instead, just because of its [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)? Is it faster than what I could possibly implement using OpenCV (considering the Keras one lacks some of the features that I may need, though I'm not sure if I really need them)?

Or, if you can't answer definitely, please just share your experience of data augmentation optimization. If you have ever benchmarked (compared speed performance) of something similar, please share as well. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**PS:** the data are loaded from HDD.

Comment: Why can't you use the ImageDataGenerator in your TensorFlow training pipeline?

Comment: @marcopah maybe I framed the question not quite correctly (will edit soon), my question is how **optimized** is the ImageDataGenerator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please keep in mind that you don't need the whole `ImageDataGenerator` to be able to use their data augmentation. Take a look at the [`image.py`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image.py) module of `keras-preprocessing` - you have all you need here! Just import all you need. For example:

```py
# For any rotation/skewing/shifting/zooming
from keras.preprocessing.image import apply_affine_transform

# To play with brightness
from keras.preprocessing.image import random_brightness
from keras.preprocessing.image import apply_brightness_shift

# ... and more
```

It seems like `ImageDataGenerator` uses `PIL` to read images, which is much more slower than `cv2`  according to my measurements.

Also, as **marcopah** mentioned, you can optimize your data feeding pipeline (eliminate python, only `tf.Queue`).

Answer (score 5):

Just posting this in case someone find this helpful.

I would suggest to take a look at [imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug).
You can install it using pip:

```
pip install imgaug
```

In my experience it has lots of options for augmentation and it's pretty fast but i don't know if it fits your need. You may wanna check it.

Here are some examples:
[image]

Comment: `imgaug ` it's powerfull than Image Augmentation from Keras, and more customizable. 

It's (this is an empiric statement) 15% slower, but gives more flexibility. 

One thing that I recommend it's to reshape the image *before* do the augmentation.

Answer (score 2):

The Keras `ImageDataGenerator`is in my experience fast enough for most use cases. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/8cowtx/d_how_do_you_use_tensorflow_opinion_on/) reddit thread has some discussion about online data augmentation and [this](http://tensorpack.readthedocs.io/tutorial/efficient-dataflow.html) tutorial has some guidance in setting up a efficient dataflow.